# Examples of good questions

Tags: discussion, expert-level-questions

I want to put together a list of the kind of questions we want to see on this site as well as good examples of each of kind. I want to make this list so that we can point newcomers (for example, friends that we might invite that are new to the stackexchange community) so that they can get an idea of it's usefulness.

For example, these are some of the kinds of questions
I expect and would like to see:

- Evaluation of the results in some journal article

  - [Unemployment and the Minimum Wage---what are the main counter-arguments to Card and Krueger?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/47/unemployment-and-the-minimum-wage-what-are-the-main-counter-arguments-to-card)
- Clarification of some concept

  - [What is structural estimation compared to reduced form estimation?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/180/what-is-structural-estimation-compared-to-reduced-form-estimation)
- Request for suggestions on where to find data

  - [Where can I find data on income and social mobility over time? How far back is data available?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/179/where-can-i-find-data-on-income-and-social-mobility-over-time-how-far-back-is-d)
- Evaluation of Current Events

  - (Any suggestions of good questions here?)

It would be nice if answers could

1. suggest a category of questions that I have not yet thought to include on this list,
2. maybe a brief comment about why these kinds of questions are welcome on the site,
3. and give an example or two of good questions that fall into this category.

It would probably good to make a new answer for each new category or suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps the [list of Economics questions ordered by vote descending](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) would be helpful too.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to see things more targeted at the experts who we hope will populate the site. How about the things noted in this great [meta question](http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/62/what-do-experts-expect-to-get-out-of-this-se-site) from a little while back? The top-rated answers there are, I think, an excellent reflection of what the experts I've spoken with generally want out of a site like this. Those types of categories should probably be in a list like you're hoping to create.

Answer (score 4):

## Request for Clearer Explanation (for pedagogical purposes)

- [How to intuitively understand the 'Intuitive criterion'?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/225/how-to-intuitively-understand-the-intuitive-criterion)

This is a nice question. The site could be a nice place to find ideas on how to better explain difficult concepts.

Answer (score 2):

I am hoping to see more of this type of question on Econ SE:

[Can Dynare solve general equilibrium (GE) models with non-convex adjustment costs?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/2979/can-dynare-solve-general-equilibrium-ge-models-with-non-convex-adjustment-cost)

This is a "tools used by experts" question, which generally can only be answered by experts. This is one of the things this site is specifically geared towards and I'm happy to see it, would love to see more of this type.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to see more of these too. I was thinking that it might be a good idea to try to "seed" the site by asking a few basic Dynare questions. I think this would be a good idea because I'm afraid that some people might not realize that they can ask those kind of questions here. Also, it would be nice because then EC.SE would show up in more search engine results and this would bring more of these kind of users in.

Answer (score 1):

## Book recommendations

- [Graduate Level Textbook on Labor Economics and Macro-Labor](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/471/graduate-level-textbook-on-labor-economics-and-macro-labor)
- [Book recommendations on empirical methods in economic research and econometrics?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/110/book-recommendations-on-empirical-methods-in-economic-research-and-econometrics)

Sometimes it can be hard to find good study material. Stackexchange can be a nice resource for references.

Comment: In principle I agree, but I dislike that particular question for its broadness. Look at the answers, which suggest all kinds of books.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm willing to edit the post to replace the example or add other, better examples to it. Do you have an example of a good post of this sort? Maybe even one from a different SE site?

Comment: I didn't have an example, and we should have examples from our own site. So I posted a question which I felt was specific enough: http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/471/graduate-level-textbook-on-laboreconomics-and-macro-labor